# DVD Menu Creation in .NET

Tags: .net, dvd

Does anyone know of a good component for .NET that will allow me to create a menu and .iso for a DVD?  For each DVD I have several video files and photos that I'd like to turn into a DVD automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RocketDVD Professional](http://www.dmapp.com/index.php?option=com_products&task=view&cid=15&Itemid=43) may be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

YMMV, but it is unlikely that you would find a drop-in component that would do this. DVD authoring is a very involved task, and generally only implemented in full software packages that support the whole process end-to-end.

That said, there are some OSS projects out there that do DVD authoring (e.g., dvdauthor, DVDStyler, etc.) that you might be able to incorporate into your project, subject to their respective licenses of course. I'm not aware of any .NET ones, and again the focus of these is generally to actually do the authoring, not expose an API, but a lot of them do use XML (or similar) files to describe menus and such, so you may be able to generate these from .NET and then shell out to them to do the work. That's about as close as you'd likely get without doing a LOT of work yourself, however.

The other option would be to find a commercial package with a scripting or automation engine, although these tend to be the higher-end ones that are very expensive.